# How to load a page through ajax and jquery in cold fusion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I run this script I am getting `AjaxFunction is undefined`. I have searched and know that it is not defined in proper scope but can anyone let me know what is the correct way to define it and what is the reason for the error.

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
  function(AjaxFunction) {
    alert(“test”);

    $.ajax({
      type: “GET”,
      url: “cfquery.cfm”,
      success: function (res) {
        alert(res);
        document.getElementById("loadingdiv").style.display = ”block”;
        document.getElementById("loadingdiv").innerHTML = res;
      }
    });
  };
</script>

<cfform id="PageloadAjax" name="PageloadAjax">
  <div id="Displayingdiv" name="displayingdiv">
    <cfinput id="CFQUERYbutton" name="CFQUERYbutton" type="button" value="Displaypage" onclick="AjaxFunction">
  </div>
  <div id="loadingdiv" name="loadingdiv"></div>
</cfform>
```

Comment: `function(AjaxFunction) {` should be `function AjaxFunction() {` and `onclick="AjaxFunction"` should be `onclick="AjaxFunction()"` - or better yet a unobtrusive event handler. Also note that some of your double quotes are invalid. use `"` or `'`, not `”`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    the answer that perfectly worked for me is:

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function AjaxFunction(mode) {
            var url="";
            if ( mode =="contacts") url = "cfquery.cfm";
            if ( mode =="tagsvsscripts") url = "cfqueryprogram.cfm";
            if ( mode =="siteinfo") url = "CFtagsvsscripts.cfm";
            if ( mode =="Jqueryhide") url = "dynamic.cfm";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    success: function (res) {
                        $("#results").addClass("loading");
                document.getElementById("loadingdiv").style.display="block";
                        $("#results").html(res);
                        $("#results").removeClass("loading");
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

       <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-header bg-secondary">
            Ajax Page Load Example Using Bootstrap
        </div>

        <div class="card-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-2 col-form-label">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="CFQUERYbutton" 
     type="button" value="Displaypage" onclick="AjaxFunction('Jqueryhide')">
                    <br><input class="btn btn-primary" 
   name="CFQUERYbutton" type="button" value="Displaypage" 
    onclick="AjaxFunction('contacts')">
                    <br><input class="btn btn-primary" 
    name="CFQUERYbutton" type="button" value="Displaypage" 
    onclick="AjaxFunction('tagsvsscripts')">
                        <br><input class="btn btn-primary" 
    name="CFQUERYbutton" type="button" value="Displaypage" 
    onclick="AjaxFunction('siteinfo')">
                    </div>
                    <div id="loadingdiv" name="loadingdiv">

                    </div>
                    <div id="results"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are defining an anonymous function with AjaxFunction as a parameter. Step one in getting this to works is to change

```
function(AjaxFunction) {...}
```

into

```
function AjaxFunction() {...}
```

Also, in the onClick attribute, you must call the function, not just name it. So change

```
onclick="AjaxFunction"
```

into

```
onclick="AjaxFunction()"
```

I recommend looking at some basic JavaScript material to more easily understand and solve these minor issues. You could start with [W3 Schools](http://w3schools.com/) for easily understandable tutorials, or [You don't know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/up%20%26%20going) if you want more in-depth JavaScript knowledge.

Comment: Thank you so much I have edited my answer as per your suggestion but again I am getting "AjaxFunction is not defined" error. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: There might be another syntax error in the script, I'm not sure if ColdFusion tries to evaluate it or something. Your editor seems to be using the wrong kind of quotation marks, change your `”` into `'` or `"`, since the current code is not valid JavaScript. This could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
    function AjaxFunction() {
        alert(“test”);
            $.ajax({
            type: “GET”,
            url: “cfquery.cfm”,
            success: function (res) {
            alert(res);
            document.getElementById("loadingdiv").style.display=”block”;
            document.getElementById("loadingdiv").innerHTML=res;
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

And call function in `onclick = "AjaxFunction()"`.